# Why is ajax only displaying last data

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to retrieve data from my db via ajax, console.log show the all  results as I would like, however in my html it displays only one result which is the last data. Why is this? Can someone please help me?

Easy on answer as i'm a newbie :)

### My code below;

### HTML

```
<div class="mI">            

        <section>
                <div class="pM" id="m1"></div>
            </form>
        </section>

        <aside class="mBI">
            <div class="mT">
                <p id="m2"></p>
            </div>

            <p id="mG"></p>
            <p style="margin-top:-8px" id="m3"></p>

        </aside>    
</div>
```

---

### JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    function connect2mO() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "tes.php",
            type: "GET",
            //data:"",
            dataType: "json",
            //async:false,
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function() {
                    var mP = this.p;
                    var mT = this.t;
                    var mG = this.g;

                    console.log(mP);
                    console.log(mT);
                    console.log(mG);


                    $('#m1').html('<img src="p/' + mP + '"/>');
                    $('#m2').html(mT);
                    $('#m3').html(mG);
                });
            },
            error: function connect2mO() {
                alert('error loading mO');
            }
        });
    }
    if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', connect2mO);
    } else if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', connect2mO, false);
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('load', connect2mO, false);
    }
});
```

---

### PHP

```
<?php
        include ('session_start.php');        
        include ('db_connect_mO.php');

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mo ORDER BY mRD");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) 

        {           
            $test[]= array( 
                            'p'=> $row['mP'],
                            't'=> $row['mT'],
                            'g'=> $row['mG'],
                        );
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode ($test);

        //detailed error reporting
        if (!$sql) 
        {
            echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($db);
        exit;

        }
?>
```

What the code below will output in php its what I am trying to achieve using ajax.

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { ?>

<div class="mI">            

        <section>
                <div class="pM"><img src="p/<?php echo $row["mP"];?>" alt=""/></div>
        </section>

        <aside class="mBI">
            <div class="mT">
                <p><?php echo $row["mT"];?></p>
            </div>

            <p id="mG"></p>
            <p style="margin-top:-8px"><?php echo $row["mG"];?></p>

        </aside>    
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It is because you are using `.html()` in your `$.each()` loops. You need to use `.append()` instead so that they don't overwrite the last value.

Comment: Thanks @Sean, I already tried .append() it shows me all the results quite alright but it isn't displayed properly. Like it dumps all the results into the html elements instead one after the other. e.g instead of results 1 => html element, results 2 => html,  .it does result 1 and result 2 => html

Comment: for that you need to create the html part dynamically @chiboz

Comment: Please how can I do that @Kanudo?

Comment: The other option would be grab the existing `html()` into a var, concat your new value to that, and then stick it back with `html(value)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
      var data = [{'p': 'p1', 't':'t1', 'g': 'g1'},{'p': 'p2', 't':'t2', 'g': 'g2'},{'p': 'p3', 't':'t3', 'g': 'g3'}];

          $.each(data, function() {

            $.each(this, function(key,value) {

              var display = '<div>'+ key +' = ' +value+ ' </div>';

              $('body').append(display);

            });

          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For your code you can do it like this

```js
var data = [{'p': 'p1', 't':'t1', 'g': 'g1'},{'p': 'p2', 't':'t2', 'g': 'g2'},{'p': 'p3', 't':'t3', 'g': 'g3'}];

    $.each(data, function() {

    var html = '<hr>'+

    '<div class="mI">'+     

        '<section>'+
                '<div class="pM" >' + this.p + '</div>'+
            '</form>'+
        '</section>'+

        '<aside class="mBI">'+

            '<div class="mT">'+
                '<p>' + this.t + '</p>'+
            '</div>'+

            '<p></p>'+
            '<p style="margin-top:-8px" id="m3">' + this.g + '</p>'+

        '</aside>'+    
    '</div>';

    $('body').append(html);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes its working, not displaying perfectly yet but I think I get the idea now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to handle the display by CSS

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
     $('#m1').html('<img src="p/' + mP + '"/>');
     $('#m2').html(mT);
     $('#m3').html(mG);
```

which just overwrites the values with this which appends:

```
      $('#m1').html($('#m1').html() + '<img src="p/' + mP + '"/>');
      $('#m2').html($('#m2').html() + mT);
      $('#m3').html($('#m3').html() + mG);
```